# Windows XP Mode on Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

Our company have made the jump from Windows 7 to Windows 10. However, there are still some departments that use legacy software requiring Windows XP. To get round this we have used XP Mode in Windows 7 previously.

Windows 10 doesn't come with XP Mode, so i tried to copy the VHD from XPMODE folder and create a copy in Virtual Box as an alternative. But keeps asking me to register the XPMODE computer, even with a legit code it won't register.

Has anyone come up with a solution for this or had any luck transfering from XPMODE to Virtual Box. Or even have a better solution to resolve this?

Comment: The reason you are being asked to activate has to do with you using Virtualbox.  You should have more luck using a Hyper-V machine instead although that isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Ramhound is correct. There are modified BIOSes that allow running XP mode under VirtualBox, but their compliance with XP mode license is arguable.

Comment: So without having to recreate the virtual machine and reinstall the the software as its a pain to configure. I should be able to run it in HyperV instead?

Comment: Ramhound can you put your suggestion as an answer and i'll mark it as the answer. It has worked. I just need to get the virtual switch to work properly.

Comment: gronostaj Can you also submit yours as an answer and i'll upvote it as the information is incredibly handy to know.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to migrate the existing installation of windows xp mode for Windows 10 with a modified bios using the VmWare Workstation.
I tested with VmWare version 11.1.2 and it worked perfectly.
 That can be done also with VirtualBox

Comment: I would have liked to try VmWare however my department head has not got the budget in this years business plan to do spend on VmWare for the amount of machines we need XPMode for.